# Self Learning, textbooks

Tags: education

I was thinking of getting the Pearson textbooks for Algebra, Trigonometry, and Calculus. I need to review Algebra and Trigonometry. Calculus I will be self teaching.

Does anyone have another suggestion than that publisher?

Also, to further understand the material of space exploration, what math textbooks beyond the basics listed above are recommended? What physics books are recommended for a basic understanding?

Comment: *Welcome to Space!* There's answers for part of your question in the meta section: [Resources and references on the topic of space exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/249/12102) but your question doesn't fit this site's scope because it's pretty open-ended. There isn't likely to be a right answer, several people could express very different opinions in different answers. Stack Exchange is a little different than other sites you may have used. Have a look around at other question, and if you can think of a more specific question feel free to post a new one.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)  and also [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://space.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) With almost 10,000 questions here and 91% with accepted answers, you might consider this site an excellent source for self-learning as well!

Comment: Orbital Mechanics 2nd edition is what I was reading for awhile. I really enjoyed it. I would suggest it unless anyone has a reason to counter why its out of date or something.